# Better way to turn time series spikes/high frequencies into discrete signals?

Tags: discrete-signals, python, time-series

I am just wondering if there is a better way to transform time series data spikes/high frequencies into discrete signals?

Currently, I have time series data that I am applying a median filter to loop through and filter large spikes.  I am just using the standard deviation to find the lower and upper regions of my stationary signal.  Once everything is removed but the spikes, I take the sign of the value to get a discrete signal.

[image]

[image]

Currently it works but I’m wondering if there is a better method that can be utilized...

Comment: well, "better" way: for which purpose?

Comment: If you look around the 800 mark, the median filter oscillates between 1, -1 before it starts developing clean signals again. A better method would not oscillate as much and have cleaner signals.

Comment: again, *why* is that better? what is the *purpose* of this analysis? It's way easier helping someone with toolmaking who tells you what they want to achieve with that tool than just someone who only tells you what's wrong with their current tool.

Comment: Trying to clearly label data where the rate of change is abnormal compared to the mean of the running signal.  Would like to train a machine learning algo

Comment: so the spiky signal is the rate of change of some other signal?

Comment: Thank you, yes it is a ROC signal

Comment: could you then define what you mean with "big spikes", specifically (and maybe what you *don't* mean with it)? for example, why doesn't singly applying an (absolute) threshold work for you?

Comment: I would like to try and have a filter that is adaptive and try to isolate label little oscillations as well as larger oscillations right when the ROC is highest.  Currently looking into minima and maxima formulas.  Still learning DSP and trying to see what are the apps for different filters

Comment: I'm sorry, but "little" and "larger" are very ambiguous terms; so is "oscillations": you really need to define these in a way that I can "human parse" them :)

Comment: maybe just an (annotated) zooming in on each of both types would help.